# PHP Covariance with inherited class - Declarations incompatibles

Tags: php, covariance

I would like create an abstract class with abstract method which allow abstract type in return type. In my final class, I would like override type returned with type which implement abstract type initially declared.

```php
<?php

abstract class A {
    abstract public function test(A $foo): self;
}

class B extends A {
    public function test(B $foo): self
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This compilation error is thrown:

```sh
Fatal error: Declaration of B::test(B $foo): B must be compatible with A::test(A $foo): A in ... on line 8
```

[In documentation, covariance is explained with interface.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php#language.oop5.variance.covariance) But not with abstract class. More about PHP implementation, the documentation say:

> In PHP 7.2.0, partial contravariance was introduced by removing type restrictions on parameters in a child method. As of PHP 7.4.0, full covariance and contravariance support was added.

I'm using PHP 7.4.

Comment: The child needs to accept more generic parameters not more specific ones. It can return more specific ones though so the `:self` return type should be allowed

Comment: True, I can returned more specific type. Is it possible to accept more specific type in child ? I think it's a generic use-case.

Comment: That would break [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) so it shouldn't be possible in OOP. But since this is PHP you can just omit type restrictions and pass whatever you want and do type validation in the method body. Imagine if you have a class `C extends A` , `A` should be able to accept that, and by extension so should `B` but in your case it will not be able to.

Comment: I didn't perceive that my use case "broken" the OOP. I understand this concept. It's relentless. If you want write a response, I valid it.

Comment: What PHP/7.4 allows is [this](https://3v4l.org/hPjvg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quite core principle of object oriented programming is the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which essentially boils down to:

> if `S` is a subtype of `T,` then objects of type `T` in a program may be replaced with objects of type `S` without altering any of the desirable properties of that program

The way to achieve this is by having *covariant* method return types, *contravariant* method type arguments. Exceptions thrown kind of count as return types here so they also need to be covariant.

What you need is *covariance* of type arguments which breaks this principle.
The reason why can be seen by considering the example below:

```php
abstract class A {
    abstract public function test(A $foo): self;
}

class C extends A {
    public function test(C $foo): self {
        return $this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function test(B $foo): self {
        return $this;
    }
}

$b = new B();
$c = new C();

$b->test($c); // Does not work
((A)$b)->test((A)$c); // Works
```

In the example above, you don't allow `B::test` to accept any type other than `B` as a type argument. However since `B` itself is a child of `A` and `C` is also a child of `A` by simple down-casting (which is allowed) the restriction is bypassed. You could always disable down-casting but that's almost saying you're disabling inheritance which is a core principle of OOP.

Now of course there are compelling reasons to allow covariance of type arguments, which is why some languages (such as e.g. [Eiffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language))) allow it, however this is recognised to be a problem and even has been given the name [*CATcalling*](https://www.eiffel.org/node/251) (CAT stands for Changed Availability or Type).

In PHP you can attempt to do runtime checks to remedy this situation:

```php
abstract class A {
    public function test(A $foo) {
         // static keyword resolve to the current object type at runtime 
         if (!$foo instanceof static) { throw new Exception(); }  
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public function test(A $foo): self {
        parent::test($foo);
        return $this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function test(A $foo): self {
        parent::test($foo);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

However this is a bit messy and possibly unnecessary.

Comment: Your example doesn't work (as of PHP 8.2): `PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of C::test(C $foo): C must be compatible with A::test(A $foo): A`

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin the first code was not intended to be working code but an example of what could go wrong if the code was actually allowed to work in PHP. The 2nd one had an extra `abstract` which I removed